# Iterating a list to apply a function to each element from current position

Tags: python, algorithm

Let's say I have a list with the following values:

```
values=['foo','bar','lorem','ipsum']
```

I want that for every element of the list, iterates the entire list adding up the length of the current item + all the other lengths.
This is done by a function that does the following:

```
def sum_length(first_string,second_string):
    return len(first_string)+len(second_string)
```

My code looks like this

```
for i,_ in enumerate(values):
    counter=i
    while counter < len(values):
        print(sum_length(values[i],values[counter]))
        counter+=1
```

So the first iteration would be

```
1. len('foo') + len('bar')
2. len('foo') + len('lorem')
3. len('foo') + len('ipsum')
```

Second:

```
1. len('bar') + len('lorem')
2. len('bar') + len('ipsum')
```

This is not very effective with very big lists or more complex functions, how could I improve my running time?

Comment: The current length + all other lengths is the same number for every element: `sum(len(s) for s in values)`.

Comment: your code doesn't work as of now.

Comment: It will be helpful if you would add expected output. If you want to save each step result `accumulate` from `itertools` will be good for you. Something like `accumulate(map(len, values))`

Comment: adde d example of first two iterations and fixed code, it's not about the problem it self but how to improve iteration of this process and execution time

Comment: As described and implemented, your problem/solution is going to be `O(N^2)`. You're probably not going to get a significant improvement over your current approach, unless the function you're computing on each element (in this case `len()`) takes more than constant time. If I had to guess, I'd say your actual problem probably doesn't actually require iterating over every pairwise sum.

Answer (score 2):

With given example here is the solution:

```py
from itertools import combinations

for (w1, w2) in combinations(values):
    print(len(w1) + len(w2))
```

In terms of optimization you can first convert your values list to list of their lengths and then do the script but without calling `len`

Answer (score 0):

```py
values=['foo','bar','lorem','ipsum']
print(sum(len(i) for i in values))
```

is this what ur looking for?

Comment: Not really, added examples